# Necessary to clean every time when building with XCode 4?

Tags: xcode, build

As the title states, if I don't clean my project before building, neither the simulator nor the iPhone is able to get my most recent code changes.  Has anyone else experienced this problem or does anyone know of a fix?

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem right now, but it didn't start until I started using a workspace with multiple projects. I don't think the answer below is right. How can you be required to clean every time? That requires a full rebuild for every change you make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I upgraded versions, this problem went away on it's own. It must have been a bug or a configuration issue of some kind, so I'm marking this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Although I haven't experienced it a lot. Plus its recommended. If you watch iPhone Dev Videos taught at stanford by Alan Cannistraro (One of the Apple engineer's who worked on Cocoa Touch framwworks) recommends doing that.